# grails 3: Generate project docs pdf format

Tags: pdf, grails3.2.0

I'm on Grails 3.2.3 using the project documentation feature. No problem generating good-looking HTML. But PDF? I feel intellectually challenged because I read the manual and try what I think it says,

```
gradle docs --pdf
```

(and many variations thereof not in the manual). No luck. The typical response is,

```
Unknown command-line option '--pdf'.
```

What's the correct command line to generate PDF?

I like the docs feature and have used it in several projects since Grails 2 times.

Answer (score 1):

**For pdf page**

For generate the Grails 3 doc run the `publishPdf` Task (See [publishPdf](http://docs.grails.org/3.0.2/api/grails/doc/gradle/PublishPdf.html))

**For Html page**

For generate the Grails 3 doc run the `publishGuide` Task

---

*For another info see the chapter 23.4* on the [official guide](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/contributing.html#patchesDoc)

Comment: In a recent Grails 3 version? Don't think so. There is no "doc" task, only "docs" as far as I can see.